# HTML/PHP - is it possible to return a HTML date with an empty or null value for PHP if/else statement?

Tags: php, html, date

Amateur programmer, I am trying to create an invoice writer which uses an HTML form to get 4 required weekly date ranges, and an optional fifth for a "five week month". The first four have a "required" tag as you'd expect, but when the fifth is not needed, it returns the base unix date instead of an empty string value, and then runs through the price, gst, and total functions. I am trying to make each range print out as a row in a table, like so;

```
  <tr>
          <td>'.$week_five.'</td>
          <td>$ '.$price.'</td>
          <td>$ '.gst($price).'</td>
          <td>$ '.total($price, gst($price)).'</td>
        </tr>'
```

using an if/else statement along the lines of this;

```
if (isset($_POST['start5']) && isset($_POST['end5'])) {
  $start5 = $_POST['start5'];
  $start5 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($start5));
  $end5 = $_POST['end5'];
  $end5 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($end5));
$week_five = '<p id="week_five">'.$start5.' to '.$end5.'</p>';
} else {
  $week_five = "";
}
```

So it seems like the HTML date will never return an empty or null value, even using value="". Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Edit; HTML form is

````
 <input id="end" type="date" name="end5" value="">```
````

Comment: *So it seems like the HTML date will never return an empty or null value*, I assume you are referring to the html5 `type="date"` input?

Comment: FYI, It's also possible to have a 6-week month, March 2020 is one if your week starts on Monday.

Comment: Dale, that's correct. I tried adding an empty string as a value tag, but I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Nick, right you are... Oh dear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply assign your date variable with `NULL`, no quotes.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

```
$week_five = NULL;
```

OKAY to reset the POST, do the following

```
if(isset($_POST["start5"]) && isset($_POST["end5"]) && $_POST["start5"] === "" && $_POST["end5"] == ""){
  $_POST["start5"] = NULL;
  $_POST["end5"] = NULL;
}
```

RESULTS: These results are from `var_dump($_POST)` coming from HTML 5 `type="date"` input fields on submit

```
var_dump($_POST) => array(3) { ["start5"]=> NULL ["end5"]=> NULL ["submit"]=> string(6) "submit" }
```

Comment: Dale, still shows the base unix date. Is isset the problem? It seems like even a default value is still going to be a "set" value for the php part.

Comment: are you talking about the posts?

Comment: please add your steps to reproduce your issue to your question

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the table output after the php validation shows like this;  ```15/03/2020 to 20/03/2020
 $ 350.00  $ 35.00  $ 385.00
01/01/1970 to 01/01/1970
 $ 350.00  $ 35.00  $ 385.00```

Comment: So the HTML form = Week Five: <input id="start" type="date" name="start5" value=""> plus one for the end date dropdown, both left on the default "dd/mm/YYYY"

The php if/else is ```if (isset($_POST['start5']) && isset($_POST['end5'])) {
  $start5 = $_POST['start5'];
  $start5 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($start5));
  $end5 = $_POST['end5'];
  $end5 = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($end5));
$week_five = '<p id="week_five">'.$start5.' to '.$end5.'</p>';
} else {
  $week_five = "";
}```

The output is 01/01/1970 to 01/01/1970 and the price functions run

edit: not required, default